# Martingales for a random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

Firstly, I just want to check my understanding:

If we have a symmetric random walk such that

$P(S_{n+1} = S_n + 1|S_n)=1/2$

$P(S_{n+1} = S_n - 1|S_n)= 1/2$

then $S_n$ is a martingale, $(S_n)^2$ is a sub-martingale and because a martingale has a constant expectation we subtract the mean $(n)$ to get a martingale. So, $(S_n)^2 - n$ is a martingale. Is that correct?

---

Secondly, I have a question about an asymmetric random walk:

If we have a random walk such that

$P(S_{n+1} = S_n + 1|S_n)= p(<1/2)$

$P(S_{n+1} = S_n - 1|S_n)= 1-p = q$

then is $S_n$ a sub-martingale or super-martingale? I am thinking super-martingale because its expectation decreases with time, e.g.

$E[S_1] = E[X_1] = p-q$

$E[S_2] = E[X_1 + X_2] = 2(p-q)$

...

$E[S_n] = E[X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n] = n(p-q)$

where $(p-q)$ is negative so the expectation is decreasing and

$P(X_n = 1)= p(<1/2)$

$P(X_n = -1)= 1-p = q$

Therefore, I would think we have to add the mean, $n(p-q)$, to get a martingale. So, $S_n + n(p-q)$ would be a martingale. However, my lecturer says that $S_n - n(p-q)$ is a martingale and gives no explanation.

Where have I gone wrong in my thinking?

Comment: Why $Y_n=S_n+E(S_n)$ would be a martingale? If $E(S_n)=na$ with $a\ne0$, $E(Y_n)=2na\ne0$...

Comment: My thinking was that $S_n$ is a super martingale (is that correct?). Therefore, its expectation is decreasing with time so we add its expectation to get it constant with time. Have I gone wrong in my thinking?

Comment: Also, is my thinking behind the first section (about the symmetric random walk) correct?

Comment: Adding $E(S_n)$ never works, one should consider $S_n-E(S_n)$ instead.

Comment: Oh right. So if I add $E(S_n)$ in the case above, then I am actually going to take away from the martingale (since the expectation is negative). This means it will decrease even further with time. Is that correct?

Comment: Therefore, we will consider $S_n - E(S_n)$ for a martingale, for the case where $S_n$ is a sub-martingale and also the case where it is a super-martingale. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: @Did Sorry to ask, but could I please get a reply? I really need help understanding and no one else seems to help? Please could you reply?